# How can I import an ics file (URL) to Google calendar programmatically by using the Google calendar API?

Tags: android

How can I import  an ics file (URL) to Google calendar programmatically by using the Google calendar API ? I have a url of an ics file and in my program, I wanna add all the event that in the ics file to Google calendar. On Google calendar web UI I can see a function which is add calendar from url. However, I cannot find any document description of this function in Google calendar API document. Is it possible to import an ics file (url) to Google calendar by the provided api?

Comment: Also need this.